# Is it right approach to define a static object inside a function?

Tags: c++, singleton

```
class MyClass {
public:
    static MyClass& getInstance() {
        static MyClass obj;
        return obj;
    }
};


int main()
{
    MyClass& obj1 = MyClass::getInstance();
    MyClass& obj2 = MyClass::getInstance();

        |
        |

    MyClass& obj1000 = MyClass::getInstance();  
}
```

If several times getInstance() function is called, Will it always return the same object and all obj1, obj2 ... obj1000 will refer the same object.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is a valid approach and yes, all of objXXX will refer to the same object. The object will be constructed the first time the function is called.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But I have a doubt. Code inside the member function getInstance being an inline function can be replaced against every call and multiple instance can be created

Comment: @sukumar: the code may be inlined, it does not mean that the variable will be duplicated.

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill  Okay, you mean to say if getInstance is called from different function, there is a chance of creation of multiple object

Comment: @sukumar: No, that is not a risk.

Comment: By definition, ignoring threading issues, there will be only one object created, and it will only be constructed once, no matter how many times you call the function, and from where. If you call the function from multiple threads, however, you get undefined behavior, and multiple initialization is possible. As @Dennis Zickefoose points out, the newest C++ standard is finally going to make a thread-safety guarantee as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but beware threading issues. This code is subject to race conditions, if you do not call `getInstance()` before you start any other thread that will call the method.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this is legal C++ and you will always get the same object. It's known as the Singleton anti-pattern and should be avoided like the plague, because it produces horrendously unmaintainable software. Is it the right approach? Most definitely not.

Comment: Could you explain how will this code produce horrendously unmaintainable software

Comment: @sukumar: An important aspect of maintenance is keeping track of, and minimising, dependencies between classes; the more dependencies a class has (that is, the tighter its coupling to the rest of the system), the harder it can be to modify it. Using explicit dependencies, and controlling how objects are created and who can access them, makes them easy to track. Dependencies on global objects (whether or not you dress them up as singletons) are much harder to track, since absolutely anything can potentially depend on them.

Comment: Also, in an object-oriented design, you should depend on *interfaces* rather than specific *implementations*. This makes it easier to test classes in isolation, including tests that they interact correctly with their dependent classes, by replacing those dependencies with "stub" implementations. You can't do that if the dependencies are global objects with a fixed type.

Comment: Having said that, there are occasions where one or two objects genuinely are used more or less everywhere, and making them globally accessible might be a cleaner solution than passing references to every object in the system. Just don't do it too often, and don't follow the classic "Singleton (anti-)pattern" by preventing multiple instances.